# How to convert CollectionChangedEventArgs to NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs in c#?

Tags: c#

I have triggered the `AssociationChanged` event in `EntityCollection` this argument is `CollectionChangeEventArgs`, in that event i need to raise the `SourceCollectionChanged` event this argument is `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`.

The below code throws the error because we can't able to pass the `CollectionChangeEventArgs`  for `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`

```
private void AssociationChanged(object sender, CollectionChangeEventArgs e)
    {
       SourceCollectionChanged(e);
    }
```

Could you please any one provide the suggestion for this.

Regards,

Farjana Parveen A

Answer (score 1):

Construct instance of `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` separately and populate its properties from `CollectionChangedEventArgs` instance.

You can also try creating class inheriting `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` depending upon your requirements.